# How do I refresh/restart the canvas to create a different plot in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I'm struggling a bit with refreshing the plot, so I'm able to run a histogram and afterwards a boxplot. I guess what is needed is either a button with a ".destroy" and afterwards "initialize window" -or maybe a refresh function in the beginning of every plot, so it is ready for a new plot.

I've tried a lot of different approaches from stackoverflow, but none seem to work correctly. Mainly I've tried with canvas.delete('all'), but it does not really work. So I'm hoping somebody on stackoverflow knows how to make it work correctly in this structure.

**Also I have to give a huge credit to the user, "j_4321". j_4321 really helped me a lot with figuring out how to plot correctly in Tkinter and how this framework is initialized!**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import Toplevel
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo, showwarning, askquestion
from tkinter import OptionMenu
from tkinter import StringVar

import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from psutil import cpu_percent
from psutil import virtual_memory
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import sklearn.cluster as cluster
import scipy.spatial.distance as sdist
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sn

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

RANDOM_STATE = 42 #used to help randomly select the data points
low_memory=False
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
style.use("ggplot")

f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)

df = None
df_nan = None
df_r = None
check_transformer = None
df_output = None
ContNum = None
GB_Classifier_score = None

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['age', 'collection_agency', 'number'])

class Analyticsapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        #tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="iconimage_kmeans.ico") #Icon for program
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Advanched analytics")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PlottingDFPage):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Advanched analytics", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, text="Plot Example", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PlottingDFPage))
        button4.pack(fill='x')
        
class PlottingDFPage(tk.Frame):    

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Plotting Dataframe", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)         

        global df, Plot_type, Plot_define
        
        def PlotMaster():

            Plot_define = Plot_type.get()

            if df is None:
                showwarning("Warning", "Read file first")
            elif Plot_define == '-Choose an option-':
                showwarning("Warning", "Choose a plot type")
            elif Plot_define == 'Histogram':
                Plot_text = "Plot set to: "+Plot_define
                showinfo(title="Results", message=Plot_text)
                HistogramDF()
            elif Plot_define == 'Scatterplot':
                Plot_text = "Plot set to: "+Plot_define
                showinfo(title="Results", message=Plot_text)
                ScatterplotDF()
            elif Plot_define == 'Boxplot':
                Plot_text = "Plot set to: "+Plot_define
                showinfo(title="Results", message=Plot_text)
                BoxplotDF()
            else: None
        
        def HistogramDF():
            
            f = None
            f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
            
            # REMOVE AFTER DF X, y generation!!!
            ax = sns.distplot(df['age'])

            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
            canvas.draw()
            canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

            toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self)
            toolbar.update()
            canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        
        def ScatterplotDF():
            
            f = None
            f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
            
            x = df['age']
            y = df['collection_agency']
            
            plt.scatter(x, y)
            plt.draw()
            
            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
            canvas.draw()
            canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

            toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self)
            toolbar.update()
            canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        
        def BoxplotDF():
            
            f = None
            f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
            
            # REMOVE AFTER DF X, y generation!!!
            boxplot_df = df.filter(['age', 'collection_agency'])
            boxplot_columns = list(boxplot_df.columns)
        
            sns.set_style('whitegrid')
            ax = sns.boxplot(x='collection_agency',y='age',data=boxplot_df)
            ax = sns.stripplot(x='collection_agency', y='age',data=boxplot_df)
            
            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
            canvas.draw()
            canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

            toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self)
            toolbar.update()
            canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        Options_plot = ['-Choose an option-', 'Histogram', 'Scatterplot', 'Boxplot']
                
        Plot_type = StringVar(self)
        Plot_type.set(Options_plot[0]) # default value
        
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text='Plot type:')
        label1.pack()
        
        dropdown1 = tk.OptionMenu(self, Plot_type, *Options_plot)
        dropdown1.pack()
        
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Run plot", command=PlotMaster)
        button1.pack(fill='x')
        
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        
app = Analyticsapp()
app.geometry('500x400')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: All you need is .pack_forget() your widgets when you don't want to see them anymore.

Comment: As a separate function or inside every function with plot? -Because I get "canvas does not exist" when trying it as a function I call by button.

Comment: You will have to use label.pack_forget(). since your label is in a class you will need to instead declare it as self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Advanched analytics", font=LARGE_FONT). Then you can reference it in a function that clears it with self.label.pack_forget().